# Different method of instantiation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, instance, allocation

What is the difference between this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

bookmarkObject *bookmark = (bookmarkObject *)[appDelegate.bookmarks objectAtIndex:i];
```

And

```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    bookmarkObject *bookmark = [[bookmarkObject alloc]init];
    bookmark = [appDelegate.bookmarks objectAtIndex:i];
```

Does it is a big problem if I don't get it? Both work but I don't get the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter leaks memory. The objectAtIndex returns a auto-released object. In the second example you leak the memory allocated by alloc.

The proper one is the first. If you're discussing instantiation, then there're usually three methods, one, like [NSArray alloc] init], another [NSArray array] - which is a shortcut to [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease] and the [array copy] which creates a copy. In all cases, but autoreleased ones you have to release memory yourself.
Objective-C is built around passing pointers. Therefor if there's some method then returns pointer, you don't have to allocate or init anything. And a general rule of thumb - whoever allocates the memory, should be responsible for releasing, or it must be autoreleased.

Comment: So the "best" one is the first ?

Comment: Crystal clear, I think I learn something big here, maybe essential for programming in obj-c

Answer (score 0):

Well, they would work the same, more or less, since your second example contains an assignment (`bookmark = [[bookmarkObject alloc] init]`) that is immediately overruled by the second assignment (`mookmark = [appDelegate.bookmarks objectAtIndex:i];`).

The second one leaks memory, though.